# How to call a function in app closing state Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3

I am trying to `upload` files from `iCloud` to `AWS S3` with help of `Transfer Utility`. Based on `AWS S3` Documentation. I have done upload and `application` `background` uploading.

Now, my problem is whenever user closed my `application` from `background` then my `uploading` process not working. I need to understand how to handle this problem and solution. I am following [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/how-to-transfer-files-with-transfer-utility.html)

```
// Inside AppDelegate 
func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    // Store the completion handler.
    AWSS3TransferUtility.interceptApplication(application, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession: identifier, completionHandler: completionHandler)
}

// Inside Upload Class
func uploadData(indexPath: indexPath, data: data) {

let data: Data = Data() // The data to upload

let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()
transferUtility.uploadData(data,
            bucket: S3BucketName,
            key: S3UploadKeyName,
            contentType: "image/png",
            expression: expression,
            completionHandler: completionHandler).continueWith { (task) -> AnyObject! in
                if let error = task.error {
                    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }

                if let _ = task.result {
                    // Do something with uploadTask.
                }

                return nil;
            }
}
```

Comment: Look into https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate as discussed here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html